# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable when using replacement map

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe (df1) like so:

```
Date       Value
19920507   1.02
19930602   1.11
19980802   6.07
```

and I want to remap `Date` based on a second dataframe (df2) which is like this:

```
Date1         Date2
19920507      1
19930602      2
19980802      3
```

I am replacing `Date` in the first dataframe like so:

```
list_1=df2.Date1.tolist()
list_2=df.Date2.tolist()
replacement_map = {int(i1): int(i2) for i1, i2 in zip(list_1, list_2)}

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(replacement_map)
```

but this returns:

```
 File "C:\Users\Stefano\Anaconda2_2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2220, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

  File "pandas\src\inference.pyx", line 1088, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas\lib.c:62658)

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Not callable' basically means it is not a function, and `Series.apply` accepts a function - not a dictionary.

Try [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) instead:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(replacement_map)
```

Note: To use `map`, you don't have to convert your mapping to a dictionary. A series whose indices are the keys and whose values are the dict values would do as well:

```
df1['Date'] = df1['Date'].map(df2.set_index('Date1')['Date2'])

df1
Out: 
   Date  Value
0     1   1.02
1     2   1.11
2     3   6.07
```

Of course these are all possible with [merge & join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) as well.

Comment: I really enjoy knowing I can skip the dictionary step, thank you for the suggestion